# Spring Security OAuth2 clientId and clientSecret

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am evaluating the Spring Security OAuth2 implementation. I am confused by `clientId` and `clientSecret`.

I follow https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ to build auth server.

I can get generate code by

```
http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http://example.com
```

I also can obtain the accesstoken by

```
curl acme:acmesecret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token  \
-d grant_type=authorization_code -d client_id=acme     \
-d redirect_uri=http://example.com -d code=jYWioI
{"access_token":"2219199c-966e-4466-8b7e-12bb9038c9bb","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"d193caf4-5643-4988-9a4a-1c03c9d657aa","expires_in":43199,"scope":"openid"}
```

When getting access token, the `clientId` and `clientSecret` is required.

But if I have multiple clients, should I start multiple auth server? It cannot work in this way.

How do I build OAuth2 server without `clientId` and `clientSecret`?

The code is here: https://github.com/yigubigu/spring-security-auth

Comment: also when curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" localhost:9999/uaa/user, it throws exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup may clients

Ex In Memory :-

```
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme")
                .secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                        "password").scopes("openid")
                .and()
                .withClient("xx")
                .secret("xx")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("xxx");
    }
```

Or you can add Database record for client

REF - [Spring oauth2 DB Schema](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve dynamic client registration, you need to store the credentials in database, instead of hardcoded configuration.

```
@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource())

    // ...      
}
```

Please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-dynamic-client-registration) for more info.